# Redshift SQL number of events in past n days

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a SQL table in redshift that looks like:

| ID | Date | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2019-02-01 | M |
| B | 2019-02-01 | M |
| A | 2019-01-01 | M |
| C | 2019-03-01 | F |
| B | 2019-03-01 | M |
| C | 2019-02-01 | F |
| A | 2019-09-01 | M |

I want to create a column that gives a count of the number of previous records within the past 60 days, for that specific ID. The first record (datewise) for each ID should have a count 0, as  there would be no records before that one. Additionally, the input table is not grouped/sorted by ID or  Date.

For this table, the expected output would be:

| ID | Date | Gender | Number_in_past60 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2019-02-01 | M | 1 |
| B | 2019-02-01 | M | 0 |
| A | 2019-01-01 | M | 0 |
| C | 2019-03-01 | F | 1 |
| B | 2019-03-01 | M | 1 |
| C | 2019-02-01 | F | 0 |
| A | 2019-09-01 | M | 0 |

The rows in the output table do not necessarily have to be in the same order as the input table.   Any order/grouping is OK, as long as the new `count` column is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really fast but should do the job

```sql
select 
  t_ext.*, 
  (
    select count(*) 
    from _table as t_int 
    where t_int."ID" = t_ext."ID"
    and t_int."Date" between t_ext."Date" - 60 and t_ext."Date" - 1
  ) as "Number_in_past60"
from _table as t_ext;
```

Comment: Would you need to switch the the order of the date ranges? i.e. use
`between t_ext."Date" - 60 and t_ext."Date" - 1` instead?

Answer (score 1):

general direction might looks like that, although it might require some tuning on a real data I guess

```sql
with dates as (
    select date, id
    from mytable
),
grouped as (
    select
        t.id, count(*) cnt_past60_days
    from mytable t
        join dates d on t.id = d.id 
                         and date_diff('day', t.date, d.date) between -60 and 0
    group by 1
)
select t1.*, g.cnt_past60_days
from mytable t1
    left join grouped g on t1.id = g.id and t1.createddate = g.date
```